# Vue.js: Why is there a white screen in between sliding transitions instead of the next component view?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, components, vue-router

I am using a slide transition for the components, yet the sliding screen appears white for a few seconds before the actual component is shown. How do I make it flow instantly to the next view?

This is what I am using for the transition which is wrapped in my main app.vue router-view element:

```
.slide-leave-active,
.slide-enter-active {
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.slide-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
.slide-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

---

```
<template lang="pug">
    div
        transition(name="slide")
            router-view
</template>
```

Comment: I believe the reason for this is that vue-router doesn't load the next view until the previous one has been completely removed. This causes the transition to not have anything to display until the creation of the next component. I don't know how to change it though.

Comment: in the transition example from vue-router it shows a `mode="out-in"` attached to the transition have you tried adding that directive to your transition?